# BigQuery TableResult casting options

Tags: java, kotlin, jdbc, google-bigquery, jdbctemplate

How can I cast the TableResult to the following format `List<Map<String, Any>>`

Map contains the columns and its value respectively. Multiple rows are added to the list.

I tried something like this, but it throws an error -> `com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult cannot be cast to java.util.List`

```
            val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                modSql
            )
                .setUseLegacySql(false).build()
            val queryJob = bigQuery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).build())
            val result = queryJob.getQueryResults()
            return result as List<Map<String, Any>>;
```

How can we replicate something similar to jdbc template. For example with jdbc template we can do this way

```
jdbc.query(sql, rowMapper)
```

and this returns the result in specific rowMapper format. How can we achieve this using BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a similar to Spring's API, you need to:

1. Declare the same interface:

```
fun interface RowMapper<T> {
    fun mapRow(row: FieldValueList, rowNum: Int): T
}
```

2. Come up with some way to include `RowMapper` into the query result transformation pipeline. For instance, via extension method for `TableResult` class:

```kotlin
fun <T> TableResult.mapWith(rowMapper: RowMapper<T>): Iterable<T> = Iterable {
    iterator {
        yieldAll(iterateAll().withIndex().map { (index, row) -> rowMapper.mapRow(row, index) })
    }
}
```

`RowMapper` implementation returning column names mapped to their values:

```kotlin
class RowMapperToMap(schema: Schema) : RowMapper<Map<String, Any>> {
    private val fieldsNames = schema.fields.map { it.name }

    override fun mapRow(row: FieldValueList, rowNum: Int) = fieldsNames.associateWith { row.get(it).value }
}
```

Usage:

```
val result = queryJob.getQueryResults()
return result.mapWith(RowMapperToMap(result.schema))
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. This worked like a charm! Appreciate it.

Comment: At the same time, can we modify the columns names to lower case in this logic?

Comment: Yes, just add one more transformation in `RowMapper` implementation: `fieldsNames.associateWith { row.get(it) }.mapKeys { it.key.lowercase() }`

Comment: Problem with the solution is, at the end all the values are being produced as a string rather than whats declared on the table

Comment: Actually, `row.get(it)` returns a [`FieldValue`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/FieldValue.html). It's a wrapper class for the underlying value of arbitrary type. To get it in the most generic form (`Object`), it needs one more transformation: `row.get(it).value`. Updated my answer.